# actionListener and combination of loop with if-else

Tags: java, swing, loops

I'm working on a digital attendance system. I'm using the following code in `actionPerformed`:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i ++) {
            if (ae.getSource () == buttons[i]) {
                switch (available[i]) {
                    case 1: {
                        available[i] = 0;
                        names.remove (unames[i]);
                        System.out.println ("removing " + unames[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 0: {
                        available[i] = 1;
                        names.add (unames[i]);
                        System.out.println ("at A adding" + unames[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                    default: System.out.println ("Default");
                }
                //System.out.println (names);
            }
        }
```

But, during executing both the println works one after the other..

Comment: Can you post the full code please?

Comment: Are you sure it's working for the same value of i. This can be confirmed by printing the value of i as well.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). @Sela note that `[mre]` is a magic link that expands to [mre]. We **don't** want people to post the full code.